# Ionic delete plugins from platform after update

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

After running the `ionic platform update ios` command my plugins will not be recognized any more, while running the iOS app in the simulator. It pops up with a warning that the Device plugin is not recognized and I should check the config.xml. I find it really strange because everything was fine after running the `ionic platform add ios` command (even after removing and adding again). If I restore the CDVDevice.m, CDVDevice.h in the plugin directory and the project.pbxproj inside my Xcode project everything is also working again. Is there a workaround where the update command will just do all the work for me? My config.xml is included below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.MYAPP" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>MYAPP</name>
<description>An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
</feature>
<feature name="HandleOpenUrl">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVHandleOpenURL" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="IntentAndNavigationFilter">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="GestureHandler">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGestureHandler" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="Console">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="Keyboard">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard" />
</feature>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="500" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
<engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run 'ionic state save' to save your plugins and platforms. It will the references in your package.json file. Run 'ionic state restore' to restore all your plugins after something funky happens to your repo.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working. The plugins are still not back in the platforms/ios/appname/Plugins.
I got the problem again while starting a new project. I just used the following commands
`ionic start MyApp tabs --v2`, `ionic platform add ios`,  `ionic platform update ios`,  `ionic platform update ios`